# How can I keep my variables as private and still get the output desired?

Tags: java, private

My assignment asks us to make the following variables private as shown: private String title;
private double price; --------these variables can be found on the file Book.java.

My code isn't able to retrieve these variables because they are not visible for the file Textbook.java. How can I keep these variables private, but still get the output desired when I run the TextbookApp.java file. Here is the desired output:

[image]

Here is the output I'm getting right now:

[image]

**Book.java**

```
package assignment2;

public class Book {

private String title;
private double price; 

    public Book ()
    {
        title = "";
        price = 0.0;
    }
    
    public Book (String t, double p)
    {
        title = t;
        price = p;  
    }   
    public void setTitle(String t)
    {
        title = t; 
    }
    
    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }
    
    public void setPrice(double p)
    {
        price = p;
    }
    
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return title + " " + price; 
    }
}
```

**BookApp.java**

```
package assignment2;

public class BookApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b1 = new Book();
        b1.setTitle("John Doe");
        b1.setPrice(8.5);
        System.out.println(b1.toString());

        Book b2 = new Book("Ann Smith", 9.7);
        System.out.println(b2.toString());
    }

}
```

**Textbook.java**

```
package assignment2;

public class Textbook extends Book{
    private int courseID;
    
    public Textbook()
    {
        title = "";
        price = 0.0;
        courseID = 0;
    }
    
    public Textbook (String t, double p, int ID)
    {
        title = t;
        price = p;
        courseID = ID;
    }
    
    public void setCourseID(int ID)
    {
        courseID = ID;
    }
    
    public int getCourseID()
    {
        return courseID;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return title + " " + price + " " + courseID; 
    }
}
```

**TextbookApp.java**

```
package assignment2;

public class TextBookApp extends Textbook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b = new Book ("Ann Smith", 9.7);
        System.out.println(b.toString());
        
        Textbook tb1 = new Textbook();
        tb1.setTitle("John Doe");
        tb1.setPrice(8.5);
        tb1.setCourseID(2050);
        System.out.println(tb1.toString());
        
        Textbook tb2 = new Textbook("Ann Smith", 9.7, 3090);
        System.out.println(tb2.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the error message here as text instead of a screenshot. Also indicate which in your code causes the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the error by calling the appropriate superclass constructor or method in `Book` from your `Textbook` subclass:

```
package assignment2;

public class Textbook extends Book{
    private int courseID;
    
    public Textbook()
    {
        courseID = 0;
    }
    
    public Textbook (String t, double p, int ID)
    {
        super(t, p);
        courseID = ID;
    }
    
    public void setCourseID(int ID)
    {
        courseID = ID;
    }
    
    public int getCourseID()
    {
        return courseID;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + " " + courseID; 
    }
}
```

The no-argument constructure `Textbook()` will automatically call the no-argument constructor `Book()`, so you don't need to set `title` and `price` explicitly in `Textbook()`.